# Increasing performance of .NET 4 framework installation

Tags: .net, frameworks, installation

I have a small WPF application built in C# and requiring the .NET 4.0 framework.  Currently it requires the full .NET 4 framework but we can ultimately move down to the client profile once we remove some System.Web dependencies for the JsonSerializer.  Unfortunately the client framework is only 8 or 9 meg less in size than the full framework.

To install this small commercial tool (the WPF project) we are using AdvancedInstaller and have created a very nice and robust MSI package.  In this MSI we include the Web Installer for the .NET 4.0 framework which identifies the client's architecture and downloads (and installs) the best .NET Framework package for the current machine.  This is anywhere from 25megs to 40megs.  As our applications install is generally downloaded from the web we didn't include the full framework to speed initial download (although we ultimately have to download those components anyway).

Our issue is in the time it takes for this step to occur.  On a reasonable internet connection the download time isn't too bad but the actual installation is 4-5 minutes (while a user sits and waits)

Does anyone have any tips or tricks to increase the speed of a .NET Framework install?

I know years ago there were some options to statically link in the necessary framework DLL's and (presumabely) abstract yourself from needing the framework install.  Does anything like that still exist?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need the install of the Framework. There's really not much you can do about the install. 4-5 minutes really isn't bad, considering all it contains.

Comment: Can you include a chocolate bar or a yo-yo to keep them occupied for 5 minutes?  Or just don't include it and make it a pre-requisite.  Just like the right Windows SP is one.